# Is lang=unknown attribute valid?

Tags: html, lang

Given an HTML document in a specific language (english).

I have defined a lang attribute on the  tag :

```
<html lang="en">
```

Some texts in the page are written in another language (for example french) :

```
<span lang="fr">
  blabla...
</span>
```

But, if I can not identify the language, but I know it is NOT english, can I set "unknown" as a valid value for lang attribute?

```
<span lang="unknown">
  blabla...
</span>
```

I read this in w3c documentation, but I am not sure if "the default value is [...] unknown" means that "unknown" is a real value...

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html

*lang = language-code [CI]
This attribute specifies the base language of an element's attribute values and text content. **The default value of this attribute is unknown**.*

Comment: I don't know what 'lang' is/does, but perhaps the answer is to not use the attribute at all if it is unknown?

Comment: The value is inherited. `<body lang="en"> This is english. I don't know what language this quote is in: <q>Se trata de españoles</q></body>`. Leaving it blank claims that hte unknown language is English.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The wording in the HTML 4.01 specification is obscure; the value `unknown` is not a valid language tag, and the spec uses the word “unknown” as a normal English word. That is, the default value is a value that indicates that the language is not known, but this value is not explicitly specified.

The spec is partly outdated in this area, as it refers to a superseded RFC on language tags. The current RFC is [RFC 5646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646), Tags for Identifying Languages, also known as BCP (Best Current Practice) 47. It refers, among other things, to ISO 639-2 as regards to primary language tags, and they contain the code `und` for “undetermined”. So technically you could use `lang=und`, but the RFC says: “This          subtag SHOULD NOT be used unless a language tag is required          and language information is not available or cannot be          determined.  Omitting the language tag (where permitted) is          preferred.”

And this is the approach adopted in HTML5 RC, which says [about `lang`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml:lang-attributes): “Setting the attribute to the empty string indicates that the primary language is unknown. [BCP47]”

Thus, for text in unidentifiable language you can use e.g. `<span lang="">...</span>`.

This is, in principle, useful when you have indicated the language at a higher level of element nesting. Setting `lang=""` may mean that user agents disable spelling checks and language-specific formatting, for example, though this is still rather theoretical.

Comment: I agree, if that's what the HTML 4.01 spec says then it's badly worded.  If "unknown" is being used as an English word, then to me it says "We don't know what the default value is".  I say there should be no statement of default value at all, as section 8.1.2 covers it, and so it's only "unknown" if there's no lang attribute on the element or any ancestor element, no Content-Language header, and no language set in the UA config.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer **not setting it at all** if you don't have to.
Note that the `lang=` value will be derived from its enclosing (parent) element if it is not set.

If you are *somehow forced to set it*, setting it to the **default `unknown`** as you already suggested seems perfectly legit according to the specification.

Comment: If it's not set, it's taken from the parent element, which is known. But if the language of a html fragment is ot known?

Comment: Which is not good if you have something like this:  `<body lang="en"> This is english. I don't know what language this quote is in: <q>Se trata de españoles</q></body>`

Comment: Oswald Right, but has a box containing elements of a various amount of languages a language itself? This one seems to be `unknown` or merely `undefined` or `multiple` as well.

Comment: The lang attribute applies specifically to text content, i.e. not to child elements. However, if a child element does not define it's own lang attribute, the one from the closest ancestor that defines on is assuemd. I see no problem with that.

Comment: The value `unknown` is *not* allowed.