# Indicating unlisted or fictional languages in lang attribute

Tags: html, xml, lang

How would I indicate a language other than one listed in the IANA Language Subtag Registry, for example a fictional language?

Referring to [BCP 47](http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47) (RFCs 5646 & 4647), I’d guess that the `und` tag or the `-x` private-use indicator would be needed; but is the preferred form (*e.g.*) “`und-x-dothraki`”, “`x-dothraki`”, “`qgm-dothraki`” (using `q`+`gm` for George Martin), or something else?

Consider this example:

```html
The Ficlang words <i lang="???">foo bar</i> mean “Hello, sir” in English.
```

What would be the correct value in the `lang="???"` attribute above?

(Ideally this should include a way to distinguish between multiple non-standard languages.)

Comment: Related: _[Is `lang=unknown` attribute valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15416683/95580)_

Comment: In an earlier draft, I suggested that `lang="und"` might be appropriate in an encoding of Dante’s _Inferno_: `<i lang="und">Papé Satàn, papé Satàn aleppe!</i>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the international standard [ISO 639−2](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/), the language code `mis` denotes uncoded languages.

Yet, BCP 47 – which is an IETF document describing “Internet Best Current Practice”, not a standard – says that `mis` should not be used. The argument is rather weak: “Because the addition of other codes in the future can render its application invalid, it is inherently unstable and hence incompatible with the stability goals of BCP 47.  It is always preferable to use other subtags: either 'und' or (with prior agreement) private use subtags.”

HTML5 CR – a Candidate Recommendation by the W3C – says that if the [`lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml%3alang-attributes) value is the empty string, i.e. `lang=""`, then “it must be interpreted as meaning that the language of the node is explicitly unknown”. Current HTML recommendations do no contain such a principle, and they are rather vague as regards to special values of the `lang` attribute.

So in principle, this depends on what documents you regard as authoritative. On the other hand, it most probably has no practical impact on anything: as soon as the `lang` attribute value is not in the limited (and browser-dependent) set of language codes recognized by a browser, it most probably be treated as suppressing any language-specific processing (for the element) that a browser might have.

Comment: Quenya and Sindarin are not unlisted; they have codes `qya` and `sjn` in [ISO 639-3](http://www-01.sil.org/iso639-3/), which is one of the standards that BCP 47 refers to.

Comment: If a language has no registered tag, then there is no interoperable way to specify the language. You can use `lang=""` or `lang=und` or `lang=mis` (which is frowned upon in the BCP, but only with SHOULD NOT, not SHALL NOT). You can instead or additionally use a private-use tag, e.g.`lang=x-dothraki`, but this would be up to an agreement between you and other interested parties. I don’t quite see what you expect to achieve with the attribute, so I cannot make an informed suggestion about the choice.

Comment: You have really *changed* the question. I think you should have left it as is, accepted the answer, and posted a new question.

Comment: (If you just want to make a distinction for your own processing, like styling, using `class` attributes is the simple and safe way.)

Comment: This isn’t a mindreading game. Questions should be addressed as asked, and you can clarify a question, but should not change it. Future readers will be very confused by answers and comments that address the question you asked but then replaced by something else.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31349/discussion-between-j-c-salomon-and-jukka-k-korpela)

Answer (score 0):

(I would comment @Jukka K Korpela answer but comments are too short)

I was searching for a way to use the `lang` attribute to denote the computer language used in a `<code>` tag, and I ended up in the [MDN lang attribute page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang), which says that:

> The attribute contains a single “language tag” in the format defined in Tags for Identifying Languages (BCP47).

So the standard that must (should) be followed is CSP47. Reading [the BCP47 spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt), I found:

> [ISO639-2] has defined several codes included in the subtag
>          registry that require additional care when choosing language
>          tags.
>
> In most of these cases, where omitting the language tag is
>          permitted, such omission is preferable to using these codes.
>
> Language tags SHOULD NOT incorporate these subtags as a prefix,
>          unless the additional information conveys some value to the
>          application.

We're in this case: you provide additional information (the content of the tag is written in your fictionnal language) so it's fine to use lang attribute instead of not using it.

> The 'mul' (Multiple) primary language subtag identifies content in multiple languages.  [...]

Not our case

> The 'und' (Undetermined) primary language subtag identifies
>             linguistic content whose language is not determined.
>
> This
>             subtag SHOULD NOT be used unless a language tag is required
>             and language information is not available or cannot be
>             determined.
>
> Omitting the language tag (where permitted) is
>             preferred.  The 'und' subtag might be useful for protocols
>             that require a language tag to be provided or where a primary
>             language subtag is required (such as in "und-Latn").  The
>             'und' subtag MAY also be useful when matching language tags in
>             certain situations.

Not our case either: language is determined, it's just not in the BCP standard. Hence not using the 'und' either.

> The 'zxx' (Non-Linguistic, Not Applicable) primary language
>             subtag identifies content for which a language classification
>             is inappropriate or does not apply.  Some examples might
>             include instrumental or electronic music; sound recordings
>             consisting of nonverbal sounds; audiovisual materials with no
>             narration, dialog, printed titles, or subtitles; machine-
>             readable data files consisting of machine languages or
>             character codes; or programming source code.

Not the case of a fictionnal language (assuming your fictionnal characters are not instruments)

> The 'mis' (Uncoded) primary language subtag identifies content
>             whose language is known but that does not currently have a
>             corresponding subtag.

Seems to be your case: let's use this!

> This subtag SHOULD NOT be used.

Huh...

> Because the addition of other codes in the future can render
>             its application invalid, it is inherently unstable and hence
>             incompatible with the stability goals of BCP 47.

Oh, right, "subtag should not be used for languages that might end up in BCP47 someday"! I doubt yours would...

> It is always
>             preferable to use other subtags: either 'und' or (with prior
>             agreement) private use subtags.

That's another way to do so, you might use the `x-` language tag and consider this as a private language. Empty lang tag would not fit, as the language is known. Not setting is would be a mistake too as it's not the main stream's language.

So far I get the spec, you can either use `mis-...` or `x-...`  language tags. Please correct me if I'm mistaking (that's the way I will go soon in the same case [fictionnal language] so if I know it's a wrong way before starting code, that would be easier for me to correct! )